# Is there a GPWS volume control in the audio control panel for the B737?

Tags: boeing-737, cockpit-alerts, gpws

So, I was sitting in the front rows of an A320 and could obviously hear the AP disconnect. But I could not hear the GPWS altitude and RETARD callouts. I assume this is because the pilots set the GPWS to their headsets instead of speakers in the ACP. Is there a system on the 737NG?

Comment: I don't think you can set the GPWS only on the headsets, at least in the A320 I'm not aware you can do that.